# JavaScript: appendChild and registered event listeners

Tags: javascript, safari, dom-events

I'm using `appendChild` JavaScript method to move objects across DOM. Didn't have any problem until some user has complained that drag and drop doesn't work in **Safari Mobile** after DIV element is dropped to the table. Here is REDIPS.drag library that I'm developing: http://www.redips.net/javascript/drag-and-drop-table-content/

In a moment of dropping DIV element, DIV element is appended to the current table cell by appendChild method. It should be automatically removed from previous node to the current node. In documentation https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.appendChild is nothing written about attached event listeners to the object that is moved. I assume that event listeners attached to the object (in traditional and advanced model) should travel together with object and not to be removed.

Removing event listeners is noticed only in Safari Mobile, so it can be a BUG in Safari or I missed something.

Any suggestion is more than welcome.

Comment: MDN isn't the definitive reference, the [DOM 3](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-184E7107) spec is. But you are right, listeners should stay attached.